# ethers provider.getLogs() missing an event?

Tags: ethers.js, geth-debugging

In each onBlock I want to deterministically get the list of uniswap Pairs that changed in that block so I scan for Sync events (without an address filter).

I am running on my own geth node.

I do the below which seems to give me the right logs -- however I just found a case (After much debugging) where I misssed a log that I definitely see in etherscan for one particular swap in a particular block. How is that possible?

```
let filterLog = {
  fromBlock : blockNumber,
  toBlock : blockNumber,
  topics : [
    '0x1c411e9a96e071241c2f21f7726b17ae89e3cab4c78be50e062b03a9fffbbad1', // sync
  ]
};
await provider.getLogs(filterLog).then((logList) => {
```

Comment: Hi, nxstock-trader, did you find the solution for this? I have met same problem, but couldn't find any useful info anywhere